# Registration user with uploading image

Tags: api, laravel-8

i tried to create API using Laravel 8 and here are my code for register new user

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
 
          $validasi = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'user_id' => 'unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
            'foto_ktp' => 'file|mimes:png,jpg',
        ]);
        try {
            $fileName = time() . $request->file('foto_ktp')->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $request->file('foto_ktp')->storeAs('uploads/foto_ktp', $fileName);
            $validasi['foto_ktp'] = $path;



            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'user_id' => $request->id,
                'foto_ktp' => $request->foto_ktp,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            ]);
            $user->save();

            $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;


            return response()->json([
                'data' => $user,
                'message' => 'Account Has Successfully Created',
                'token' => $token,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                'code' => 200
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Something wrong, user was not resgistered successfully',
                'errors' => $e->getMessage(),

            ]);
        }
    }
```

when i tried the routes of API in Postman, the data will return like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "updated_at": "2023-01-02T06:54:01.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2023-01-02T06:54:01.000000Z",
        "id": 22,
        "foto_ktp": {}
    },
    "message": "Account Has Successfully Created",
    "token": "19|RXUZB40Oc35XCY4OMU6TPpqLJsmTRdFVpqsdNaS5",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "code": 200
}
```

foto_ktp will return {} and i checked it in database, foto_ktp field will store this data C:\xampp\tmp\php53D.tmp

I'm quite new in Laravel and i have tried to search any references but i haven't gotten it. Is there any suggestion what should i do? I used Laravel 8 for developing the API

Comment: When something fails, like your `foto_ktp` always debug its variable. Laravel has  function called `dd()`, so ... `dd($validasi);` and show the results in your original question, also show `dd($request->all();`

Comment: i have tried it, and it returns the path of image, but when i tried dd($user) it returns .tmp extensions of images @UnderDog

Comment: Would have loved to have seen it copy/pasted in your original question